# Python Loop through variable in URLs

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, loops, url

What I want to do here is that I want to change an user id within an url for every url and then get outputs from urls.

What I did so far:

```
import urllib
import requests
import json

url="https://api.abc.com/users/12345?api_key=5632lkjgdlg&_format=_show"

data=requests.get(url).json()
print (data['user'])
```

(I type in 'user' inside of the print because it gives all the information about a focal user in json format)

My question is that I want to change user id (which is 12345 in this url example) by giving another number (any random number) and then get the outputs from every url I type in. For example, change to 5211, for example, and get the result. And then change to 959444 and get the result and so on. I think I need to use loop to make this iterate through just by changing the numbers within an url but kept failing to do this due to difficulty splitting the original url and then changing only the user id number inside. Could anyone help me out?
Thank you so much in advance.

=====================The Next Following Question is Stated Below================

Thank you for your previous answer! I tried to build my codes more based on the answer and made it but ran into another issue. I could iterate through and fetch each user's information in a json format. The format gave me a single quote (rather than double quotes) and a weird u' notation in front of every keys in json format but I could solve this issue. Anyway, I cleaned up json format and made it in a perfect neat json format.
My plan is to convert each json into a csv file but want to stack all the json I scrape to one csv file. For example, the first json format on user1 will be converted into a csv file and user1 will be considered row1 and all the keys in json will be column names and all the corresponding values will be the values for the corresponding columns. And the second json format I scrape will convert into the same csv file but in the second row, and so on.

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
eg_data=[data['user']]
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(data['user']))
print (df)

df.to_csv('C:/Users/todd/Downloads/eg.csv')
print (df)
```

So, I found that json_normalize flattens the nested brackets so it's useful in a real world example. Also, I tried to use pandas dataframe to make it as a table. Here I have 2 questions: 1. How do I stack each json format that I scraped one by one in a row in one csv file? (If there's another way to do this without using pandas frame, that would be also appreciated) 2. As I know, pandas dataframe won't give you an output unless every row has the same number of columns. But in my case since every json format I've scraped has either 10 columns or 20 columns depending on whether a json format has nested brackets or not. In this case, how do I stack all the rows and make it in one csv file?
Comments or questions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split it into two initially and join them together every time you generate a random number

```
import random

url1="https://api.abc.com/users/"
url2="?api_key=5632lkjgdlg&_format=_show"

for i in range(4): 
    num=random.randint(1000,10000) #you can change the range here for generating a random number
    url=url1+str(num)+url2
    print(url)
```

OUTPUT

```
https://api.abc.com/users/2079?api_key=5632lkjgdlg&_format=_show
https://api.abc.com/users/2472?api_key=5632lkjgdlg&_format=_show
and so on...
```

But, if you wanted to **split at that exact place without knowing how it looks beforehand**, you can use `regex` as you know for sure that a `?` is found after this number.

```
import re
url="https://api.abc.com/users/12345?api_key=5632lkjgdlg&_format=_show"
matches=re.split('\d+(?=\?)',url)
['https://api.abc.com/users/', '?api_key=5632lkjgdlg&_format=_show']
```

Now just set

```
url1=matches[0]
url2=matches[1]
```

And use the for loop.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. I adjusted your code a bit into my context and it worked!! Thank you.

Comment: @Todd Glad it helped :)

Comment: Hello, Sruthi V. I really appreciate your comment and the following update ( I just saw this). I ran into another issue. I did my best to fix it but kept failing it for the whole day. Could I ask your comments? @Sruthi V